# issue on order of selection with html select (html)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML select dropdown with the multiple attribute.
The javascript code below lets me confirm the last selected option:

```
var pr = $("#iPRNum option:selected").last().val();
alert(pr);
```

It is working just fine if I select from top to bottom, but if I select the other way around, var pr is stuck with the first item selected.

Thank you very much...

Comment: `var pr = $("#iPRNum option:last").is(":selected").val();` ???

Comment: thanks but it's not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working here

```js
$("#iprnum").on("change", function() {
  var pr = $("#iprnum option:selected").last().val();
  alert(pr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="iprnum">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Do you need something else?

**UPDATE**

```js
 $('select').multipleSelect();
 $("#iPRNum").on("change", function() {
   var pr = $(this).val();
   alert(pr);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple-select/1.2.0/multiple-select.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple-select/1.2.0/multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select multiple="multiple" id="iPRNum">
  <option value="January">January</option>
  <option value="feb">feb</option>
  <option value="june">june</option>
  <option value="art">art</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

Working demo with multiple-select library as you want

Comment: i am so sorry. I just found it's not working because of the jquery plugin i am using. It is a plugin I downloaded from this site: http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/

Comment: So you are using plugin and from that you want last selected value? can u create jsfiddle so I can figure out easily

Comment: i'm sorry.accidentally clicked on it again..is there a way to fix my problem without sacrificing the plugin?it's for user-friendliness purposes.. :)

Comment: if i select december first, then i want to select june, the alert would still be the value of december... :(

Comment: that means you need current selected value..hold on let me update it

Comment: Did it..just remove `last()` from script..is it what you want?

Comment: good day again.i am sorry i just found out a while ago that when i select items top to bottom, the first item selected remains to be the content of my variable.is there a remedy for this?thank you again

Comment: just do `$(this).val();` in onchange function

Comment: what if i want the alert to just show the latest selected option? if i use the last(), it shows the last item selected following the order of items-so if select December, then June, the variable will still contain December. if i remove the last(),the problem would be if select June, the December, the variable will still contain June.thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: I think there is no feature in that plugin to select single last selected option..in normal I get get by focus and change and comparing both value I will have last selected value..I tried it with this plugin but it didnot work properly..so may b that doesnot support or you can do pull request into that plugin to get an answer from author :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#iPRNum").on("change", function() {
    var opt = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Try to add some explanation please.